# Short story about a blinded galactic veteran

Tags: story-identification, science-fiction-genre

I read this short SF story in an anthology in the UK, approximately 40 years ago.

This blinded (I think,but I'm not sure, that also something about his vocal cords were damaged) and half crippled old man is making his way through the urban decay city centre, a gang of very young kids accost him and start slapping him about as they try to get his credite from his pockets.

A siren whoops and a police vehicle stops, initially the kids stand their ground and call out to the police that the old man was being indecent towards them, but at the last minute they run off giggling.

The police give him a hand to his feet with a "come on Pops" but then one calls out to his colleague to take a look. The man has a medal on a cord around his neck.

It's inscribed something like "Galactic Medal of Honour for valour in xxxx battle during The xxxxx War"

The two cops shrug at each other and walk away, it was so long ago (and far far away!) that they have zero knowledge of it.

The old veteran stands weeping as he realises he's suffered so long for so little.

Comment: "Citizen of the Galaxy" by Heinlein?

Comment: I've looked through the plot of  Citizen of the Galaxy (I think I've read it many moons ago) but the tale I'm seeking was definitely a short story

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed "short story".  Too late at night I guess...

Comment: Just a note -- "Citizen of the Galaxy" was initially published as a serial in a magazine; it is possible you could have read part of it and remembered it as a short story.  But though I believe that Baslim did at some point have to defend himself against hooligans, I am pretty close to positive that he never stood weeping afterwards.

Comment: Baslim wasn't blind, as far as I recall.  He was short one or both legs (but wore prosthetics when appropriate).